# sas conditional sum into new field

Tags: sql, sas, conditional-statements

I'm new to SAS and have a simple dataset called ORIG_DATA from which I need to create a new dataset SUMMARY which shows the total by Salesman_ID by Day_ID

In essence the SUMMARY output should look like this where the numbers are the sum of totals.

```
Salesman_ID|Day_1|Day_2
A          |30   |40
B          |60   |0
C          |20   |70
```

In SQL, I do

```
Select salesman_id, 
sum(case when day_id=1 then total else 0 end) as day_1,
sum(case when day_id=2 then total else 0 end) as day_2
from ORIG_DATA group by salesman_id
```

but for this problem I'm not allowed to use proc sql. How else can I do this in SAS? Haven't the foggiest at the moment.
apologies for nontable format

ORIG_DATA as below

```
Day_ID|Salesman_ID|Other_field|total
1     |A          |R000       |10
1     |A          |R002       |20
2     |A          |R000       |10
2     |A          |R004       |30
1     |B          |R002       |20
1     |B          |R000       |40
1     |B          |R004       |0
2     |C          |R003       |40
2     |C          |R004       |10
1     |C          |R002       |20
2     |C          |R002       |20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar one:

```
proc sort data = orig_data(drop = Other_field);
by salesman_id day_id;
run;

data test (drop = total);
  retain salesman_id day_id;
    set orig_data ;
  by salesman_id day_id notsorted;

  if first.day_id then sum = total;
  else sum + total;

  if last.day_id then output;

run;

proc transpose data = test out = t(drop=_:) prefix = day_id_;
by salesman_id;
id day_id;
var sum;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem with a simple data step, see the code below. 
You need to sort the data first, and then instruct the data to work with groups where you reset the day_1 and day_2 to zero at the start of a new group and you output to the data set at the last observation.

Let me know if you have any questions.

```
data ORIG_DATA  ;
input Day_ID Salesman_ID $ Other_field $ total ;
cards ;
1  A  R000  10
1  A  R002  20
2  A  R000  10
2  A  R004  30
1  B  R002  20
1  B  R000  40
1  B  R004  0
2  C  R003  40
2  C  R004  10
1  C  R002  20
2  C  R002  20
;run;

proc sort;
   by salesman_id; 
RUN; 

data salesman_id (drop=Day_ID Other_field total); 
  set orig_data; 
  by salesman_id; 
   if first.salesman_id then do; 
     day_1 = 0; 
     day_2 = 0;
   end; 
  if day_id=1 then day_1 + total; 
  if day_id=2 then day_2 + total;
  if last.salesman_id then output; 
RUN;
```

Comment: thanks - this looks like a solution that would work with my basic knowledge!

Comment: @VasilijNevlev You should also explain the implicit retain statement seeing as the person asking is relatively new to SAS.

Comment: ah. didn't realise the tick/accept answer thing was there. have accepted! thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about this? I didn't know if you only ever have a up to two `other_field` records per `salesman_id` per `day_id`. The below will work for 1 to n records:

Input data:

```
data ORIG_DATA  ;
input Day_ID Salesman_ID $ Other_field $ total ;
cards ;
1  A  R000  10
1  A  R002  20
2  A  R000  10
2  A  R004  30
1  B  R002  20
1  B  R000  40
1  B  R004  0
2  C  R003  40
2  C  R004  10
1  C  R002  20
2  C  R002  20
;run;
```

Transpose, sum and transpose back:

```
proc sort data=ORIG_DATA ;
  by salesman_id day_id ;
proc transpose data=ORIG_DATA out=D1 ;
  by salesman_id  day_id ;
  var total ;
run ;

data D2 ;
  set D1 ;
  array D(*) col: ;
  _name_=cats('day_',day_id) ;
  by salesman_id day_id;
  total=sum(of D(*)) ; 
run ;

proc transpose data=D2 out=SUMMARY(drop=_name_) name=_name_;
  by salesman_id  ;
  var total ;
run ;

*Add zeros for missing values ;
data SUMMARY ;
  set SUMMARY ;
  array days day_: ;
  do over days ;
    if missing(days) then days=0;
  end ;
run ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Other method:

```
proc summary data=orig_data nway;
class day_id salesman_id;
var total;
output out=sum(drop=_:) sum=;
run;

proc sort data=sum;
by salesman_id day_id;
run;

proc transpose data=sum out=want(drop=_name_) prefix=day_;
by salesman_id;
var total;
run;
```